# Conditional Probabilty and definition of conditional expectation.

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

$If  p(\omega, A) = P(A|\sigma)(\omega)$  is a regular version of conditional probability, then for every  $X \in L^1 $

$E(X|\sigma)(\omega) =    \int X(x)p(\omega, dx)$

I have to show this. I have seen the exercise was asked before but with $E(f(X)|\sigma)(\omega)$ And it was proven by using indicator functions. So my question is can i do it her too?